# Cannot ping Azure SQL server from WSL2

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, wsl-2

I have my flask app running inside WSL2 Ubuntu. The app connects to a Azure SQL server. But the connection fails. I am not even able to ping the azure server from my WSL2 terminal.

The connection and ping works directly from the Windows terminal.

I have already added firewall exceptions for the ipv4 addresses of both my Windows and WSL2 Ubuntu. I have also tried opening the inbound ports for the WSL2 in my Windows Defender. But still when I ping the Azure SQL server, all my packets are lost.

I have browsed Stack Overflow but there are only solutions as to how the WSL2 can connect with the SQL server running on the Windows host. None of the questions address connecting WSL2 to an Azure SQL server.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This doesn't sound on-topic for [so]; what about the above is about programming? It seems to purely be about networking (between a container and an external host).

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the firewall ports on your database as well (there is a firewall on the SQL Server and Database level)

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/secure-database-tutorial?view=azuresql